# Android: file created not found in emulator icon

Tags: android, emulation

I have creat a new android application
after i finish coding i cant find my application in the EMulator
no other icons added on to it 
can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Check the emulator menu. It's just like a real phone, where your app isn't put on the home screen. It is going to be inside the emulator menu, with all the other apps, setting, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this one said this 

2012-07-12 10:08:58 - org.mogoo.sqlitetutorial.ActivityMain] Android Launch!

[2012-07-12 10:08:59 - org.mogoo.sqlitetutorial.ActivityMain] adb is running normally.
[2012-07-12 10:09:02 - org.mogoo.sqlitetutorial.ActivityMain] Performing org.mogoo.sqlitetutorial.ActivityMain activity launch

[2012-07-12 10:09:03 - org.mogoo.sqlitetutorial.ActivityMain] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'DroidX'

Comment: [2012-07-12 10:09:03 - org.mogoo.sqlitetutorial.ActivityMain] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'DroidX'
[2012-07-12 10:10:06 - org.mogoo.sqlitetutorial.ActivityMain] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-07-12 10:10:09 - org.mogoo.sqlitetutorial.ActivityMain] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-07-12 10:11:23 - org.mogoo.sqlitetutorial.ActivityMain] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'org.mogoo.sqlitetutorial.ActivityMain activity launch'!